# vim: search, capture & replace on different lines using regex

Tags: regex, linux, vim, replace

Relatively new linux/vim/regex user here. I want to use regex to search for a numerical patterns, capture it, and then use the captured value to append a string to the previous line. In other words...I have a file of format:

> title: description_id
>
> text: {en: '2. text description'}

I want to capture the values from the text field and append them to the beginning of the title field...to yield something like this:

> title: q2_description_id
>
> text: {en: '2. text description'}

I feel like I've come across a way to reference other lines in a search & replace but am having trouble finding that now. Or maybe a macro would be suitable. Any help would be appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
:%s/\(title: \)\(.*\n\)\(text: \D*\)\(\d*\)/\1q\4_\2\3\4/
```

Where we are searching for 4 parts:

1. `"title: "`
2. rest of line and `\n`
3. `"text: "` and everything until next digit in line
4. first string of consecutive digits in line

and spitting them back out, with 4) inserted between 1) and 2).

EDIT: Shorter solution by Peter in the comments:

```
:%s/title: \zs\ze\_.\{-}text: \D*\(\d*\)/q\1_/
```

Comment: yeah...duh...that'll do the trick. I was trying to be too fancy...because I could've sworn I've come across a method where you can reference back or forward n lines in a s&r...but it's very possible I'm confusing it with something entirely different.

Comment: 19% shorter: `:%s/title: \zs\ze\_.\{-}text: \D*\(\d*\)/q\1_/`. Using `\zs` and `\ze` to set the start and end of the match we can reduce the number of catpure groups to just one. See `:h /\zs` for more information

Answer (score 0):

Use \n for the new lines (and ^v+enter for new lines on the substitute line): A quick and not very elegant example:

```
:%s/title: description_id\n\ntext: {en: '\(\i*\)\(.*\)/title: q\1_description_id^Mtext: {en: '\1\2/
```

Comment: Use `\r` instead of `^M`

Answer (score 0):

For the following example:

> title: description_id
>
> text: {en: '2. text description'}
>
> title: description_id
>
> text: {en: '3. text description'}

you can apply the regex:

`:%s/\(^.*title: \)\(.*$\n\n.*text: {en: '\)\(\d\+\)\(.*\)/\1q\3_\2\3\4`

to transform to:

> title: q2_description_id
>
> text: {en: '2. text description'}
>
> title: q3_description_id
>
> text: {en: '3. text description'}